# Python PyQt widgets positioning in pixels

Tags: python, pyqt

Can I use pixel positioning for widgets in PyQt? I mean like in Visual Studio - you can set positions of your widget (interface object).

It's so uncomfortably to position this widgets using some grids and layers. It's not just uncomfortably, I can't make simple interface.

Comment: what would you like to do, that you think you can't do with a layout manager? °°

Comment: I just... can't make an interface. I think that programmer does not need to beat yourself just for the interface. And yes, I tried to use the Qt Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set their position with pixels.

```
widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x_pos, y_pos, x_size, y_size))
# A button located at (300, 425) of size 500 by 100
self.btn_example.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 425, 500, 100))
```